# Need help displaying a string on the app UI. (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a complete beginner in Flutter. I want to display a question/ container under the app bar. So far i have written the code, but my code doesn't change anything on the app. The answer is probably something super basic, which i am missing. Your help is greatly appreciated. This is my code so far.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyAppBarWidget(),
      theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark),
    );
  }
}

class MyAppBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.navigate_before),
          onPressed: null,
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
}
class Frage extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'question',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21, color: Colors.white),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to put in your Scaffold the body to call your class Frage, like this.... body: Frage()

Answer (score 0):

you need to put `body: Frage()` inside of your scaffold, you havent call the Frage so it wont show anything

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyAppBarWidget(),
      theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark),
    );
  }
}

class MyAppBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: const <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.navigate_before),
              onPressed: null,
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: Frage());
  }
}

class Frage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: const Center(
          child: Text(
            'question',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21, color: Colors.white),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

you still can put the `Frage` in another file and call it. the code will be more clean. and you can wrap the `Frage` inside of `Column` if you want to show more something like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyAppBarWidget(),
      theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark),
    );
  }
}

class MyAppBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: const <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.navigate_before),
              onPressed: null,
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Frage(),
              const Text('1. Hello World :)'),
              const Text('2. Hello World :)'),
              const Text('3. Hello World :)'),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class Frage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: const Text(
          'question',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21, color: Colors.white),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this class

```
class MyAppBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.navigate_before),
            onPressed: null,
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Frage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your Frage() class to body.

```
class MyAppBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.navigate_before),
            onPressed: null,
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Frage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel Roldan has answered you missed adding the body to the scaffold. I've updated your code to work

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyAppBarWidget(),
      theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark),
    );
  }
}

class MyAppBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.navigate_before),
            onPressed: null,
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Frage(), //You just missed out on the body
    );
  }
}

class Frage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'question',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21, color: Colors.white),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, add `body:` parameter to your Scaffold widget under `MyAppBarWidget()` class.
You could go something like

```
Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.navigate_before),
          onPressed: null,
        )
      ],
    ),
  body : Frage(),
);
```